# Tag in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am creating a website based on question idea (like StackOverflow).

Imagine that similar questions have same tags, and a tag can belong to one or many questions.

I am using a `SQL Server` database.

Is the right idea to create tables in database to register these tags or is there a different method/concept that I don't know to do so?

Comment: If you didn't store this data in tables where would you store it??? Your question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not dealing with huge amounts (beyond tens of millions I think) of questions and tags you can go for a design like this one:

### Question

```
QuestionId INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Question PRIMARY KEY, -- auto generated with IDENTITY or SEQUENCE
QText NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
```

### Tag

```
TagId INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Tag PRIMARY KEY, -- auto generated 
TagName NVARCHAR(128)
```

### QuestionXTag

```
QuestionXTagId INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_QuestionXTag PRIMARY KEY, -- auto generated 
QuestionId INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_QuestionXTag_Question FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Question,
TagId INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_QuestionXTag_Tag FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Tag,
CONSTRAINT UQ_QuestionXTag_QT UNIQUE (QuestionId, TagId)
```

You have an `n:n` association between `Questions` and `Tags`.

So, the short answer is **yes, it can be done in SQL Server.**

My recommendation is try storing your data in a relational database, unless there is a serious reason not to (very big data, non-homogeneous data etc.), as this way provides meaningful structures and also low-level constraints.